# usage of regular expression on numbers

Tags: c#, regex

User gives input like `4.0.9`

I have a list of such numbers in a file like `4.0.8, 4.0.9, 4.0.10` etc. In this case i have to select 4.0.9 out of this three.

But if the file contains like `4.0.8, 4.0.9+, 4.0.10` then I have to copy both `4.0.9` and `4.0.10`.

Also if it has like `4.0.8, 4.0.9, 4.0.10+` then I have to copy only `4.0.9`

I tried with regular expression in c# but doesn't suite for all test case. Any idea how to implement this logic or any in-build function available?

Comment: No internal functions available. Write your own logic - parse it to the list of version along with the information if version includes future versions and use this list when matching with specific number.

Comment: are your values always ordered? If so, you could just split by the "," and iterate through the values. If searched value contains "+" then take the following item in the array if exists.

Comment: You tried with regex... what did you try? show your code

Comment: What if the file contains `4.0.8, 4.0.9+, 4.0.10+, 4.0.11`?

Comment: @Gonzix: the values will not be in order. they are shuffled always.

Comment: @Jerry: If it contains like 4.0.8, 4.0.9+, 4.0.10+, 4.0.11 then it should copy 4.0.9, 4.0.10 and 4.0.11

Comment: MatchCollection mcnew = Regex.Matches(subVersion, @"\D");
foreach (Match m in mcnew)
{
    string toBeReplaced = Convert.ToString(m.Value);
    subVersion = subVersion.Replace(toBeReplaced, "");
}
int newSubVersion = Convert.ToInt32(subVersion);

Comment: @Sayse: I removed the dots(.) and converted it to a number and checked for greater than input version like that. But all test cases are not satisfied with my code

Comment: @SatheeshKurunthiah, if they are not in order, you question does not make sense.. And while in all examples they are in order?

Comment: I can't  catch your question exactly, What is `4.0.8, 4.0.9, 4.0.10` ? is this text content present in text file? Where you want to copy and why?

Comment: @KonradKokosa: They need not be in order. we have to check all numbers in a file with the user input. say if user gives 4.0.9 then we have to check if the file contains 4.0.9+ and if it is so then we have to copy all future version no.s

Comment: @ThirusangurajaVenkatesan: consider these are version no.s and i have file with a list of all such version no.s. If user says a particular version no then decision has to be made weather to copy that particualr version no alone are all the future version based on the '+' sign.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you requirements correctly, you can write it in the following way. Assuming you have some `list` of *versions* (unsorted), you can parse it to the helper list. Notice that I'm additionaly sorting versions from the `list`, to make logic clearer:

```
string list = "4.0.8, 4.0.9+, 4.0.10";
var versions =
list.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => new
    {
       Version = Version.Parse(s.TrimEnd('+')),
       FutureReleases = s.EndsWith("+")
    })
    .OrderBy(a => a.Version);
```

Then simply iterate through it when matching some specific `input`:

```
string input = "4.0.9";
var version = Version.Parse(input);
var output = versions.SkipWhile(a => a.Version < version);
var first = output.FirstOrDefault();
if (first != null && !first.FutureReleases)
{
    output = versions.TakeWhile(a => a.Version == version);
}
```

Here we are just omitting lower version and take single version (if `+` was not specified) or all higher additionally (if `+` was specified).

Comment: This code gives output as 4.0.9 But the result should be 4.0.9 and 4.0.10

Comment: @SatheeshKurunthiah, I've edited my answer according to your comments.